# ggplots2: add change color of points based on another vector.

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi currently I a plot that I can change color of the points based on certain cutoffs

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

x = c(0.8846, 1.1554, 0.9317, 0.9703, 0.9053, 0.9454, 1.0146, 0.9012, 
      0.9055, 1.3307)
y = c(0.9828, 1.0329, 0.131, 1.3794, 0.9273, 0.3605, 1.0259, 0.9542, 
      0.9717, 0.9357)
z= c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", 
     "g", "h", "i", "j")


df = data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z)
z <- as.vector(df$z)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + theme_bw() + 


  geom_text_repel(data = subset(df, y > 1.3), aes(label = z), 
                  box.padding = unit(0.45, "lines")) +

  geom_point(aes(colour = cut(y, c(-Inf,0.2,0.5,Inf))), size = 3) +
  # set color scales 
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "p-values",
    values = c("(-Inf,0.2]" = "blue",
               "(0.2,0.5]" = "red",
               "(0.5, Inf]" = "grey"))
```

the graph looks something like this, 
[image]

However is there a way I can change the color based on another set of vectors. 
For example say I have,

```
x2<-c("a","b")
x3<-c("f")
```

can I set it so that only points in x2 are red, and x3 are blue and the rest grey?  thanks in advance!

Comment: Like `ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = ifelse(z %in% x2, "red", ifelse(z %in% x3, "blue", "grey")))) + scale_color_identity() + geom_point(size = 3)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea.  Simply make an extra column that specifies your conditions.

```
df$condition <- "others"
df[df$z %in% c("a","b"), "condition"] <- "x2"
df[df$z %in% c("f"), "condition"] <- "x3"

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour= condition)) + theme_bw() + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  # set color scales 
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "p-values",
    values = c("x2" = "red",
               "x3" = "blue",
               "others" = "grey"))
```

[image]